# Length in multi line string

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have a multiline string as follows

```
"this is a sample
this is a second sample
same length the 1 above
this is a third sample"
```

Is there any way to find which line(s) have the maximum length (in terms of number of characters) and what is the length. In the sample above, that would be the second and third line.

Comment: Length in number of bytes or number of characters or in display width (or your sample, all 3 are the same but in the general case, they're not)? May the lines contain control characters like TAB or BS?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas no of characters

Comment: What should happen if there are several lines with the max number of characters?

Comment: just need to echo that line

Comment: You mean output all the lines that have the maximum number of characters?

Comment: yes along with their length

Answer (score 3):

```
string="this is a sample
this is a second sample
same length the 1 above
this is a third sample"

printf '%s\n' "$string" | awk -v max=-1 '
  {l = length}
  l > max {max = l; output = "Max length: " max RS}
  l == max {output = output NR ": " $0 RS}
  END {if (max >= 0) printf "%s", output}'
```

Outputs:

```
Max length: 23
2: this is a second sample
3: same length the 1 above
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "this is a sample
this is a second sample
this is a third sample" | \
while read line; do 
  echo ${#line} $line
done | sort -n
```

gives you the list of lines with length, sorted by length

Answer (score 0):

Total statistics with ***top*** longest lines using GNU ***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_desc" }
     { len=length; a[len]=(a[len])? a[len]", "NR:NR }
     END{ for(i in a) printf "Length: %s, row number(s): %s\n",i,a[i] }' file
```

The output:

```
Length: 23, row number(s): 2, 3
Length: 22, row number(s): 4
Length: 16, row number(s): 1
```